# process non csv, json and parquet files from s3 using glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

Little disclaimer have never used glue.

I have files stored in s3 that I want to process using glue but from what I saw when I tried to start a new job from a plain graph the only option I got was csv, json and parquet file formats from s3 but my files are not of these types. Is there any way processing those files using glue? or do I need to use another aws service?

I can run a bash command to turn those files to json but the command is something I need to download to a machine if there any way i can do it and than use glue on that json

Thanks.

Comment: You can program your own glue job using [ETL programming](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming.html).

Comment: can I even run a bash command to turn those files to json?